# Java very small number arithmetic operation

Tags: java, numbers, arithmetic-expressions

The result of  expression:  `2.227E-19-1.0+1.0` would be 0.0

How can I get result of  2.227E-19 ?

I have an expression

```
a-b+1
```

and

- a always be a very small number.
- b might be close to 1.0

**HOW to keep accuracy when a very small number operate with a big number ?**

Comment: What is the problem? What you get? What are the values of `a` and `b`?

Comment: `+ (1.0 - b)`. But this is a hair artificial: IEEE double has 16 digits of precision, so the smallest variation between `b` and 1 is greater than the size of `a` -- you essentially have lost all accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a `double` to store the result. It has more than enough precision for this calculation.

Comment: I don't think that's true, testing it with the given values results in 0 even with double precision.

Answer (score 0):

If you know beforehand which operands can be small, you can reorder the operations:

```
-b + 1 + a
```

This way, the part before `a` will be calculated first, and both sides (`-b+1` and `a`) will be roughly of the same magnitude, causing less floating-point problems.

Here's a relevant section of [The Java™ Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html):

> Operators on the same line have equal precedence. When operators of equal precedence appear in the same expression, a rule must govern which is evaluated first. All binary operators except for the assignment operators are evaluated from left to right;

Comment: The above yields more apparent precision but no more accuracy.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean exactly; for the case of `b=1` at least, this approach keeps `a` from being cancelled out, which is the main issue as far as I can see.

Comment: If `b` would really be `1 - 1.0E-17` if calculated in higher precision, the overall result would be quite different from 2.227E-19.  Rearranging the order to produce an apparently more precise result does not produce a more accurate result.

Answer (score 0):

Or use BigDecimal with enough scale.